# How to restrict my dataframe for all the columns values between 0 to 100 in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Can anyone help me out to restrict my dataframe for all the columns values between 0 to 100 in python:

```
if (df.loc[:,:] > 0) & (df.loc[:,:] < 100):
    print(df)
else:
    print('Data out of range')
```

Also, please find the dataframe df below:

```
Position    Marks
5.7680  56.4000
5.7680  56.4000
5.7680  56.4000
5.7680  56.4000
7.2680  56.4000
5.7680  56.4000
5.7680  56.4000
5.7680  
5.7680  56.4000
5.7680  56.4000
56.400
5.7680  56.4000
5.9680  56.4000
5.7680  56.4000
2.7680  56.4000
5.7680  56.4000
5.7680  
5.7680  56.4000
5.7680  56.4000
5.7680  56.4000
```

Comment: can you provide sample `df`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'birth_year': [1979, 50, 1977],
                'Price': [2000, 300, 375] })
df[(0<df)&(df<100)]
```

should work. Df is just a example

Based on the new information provided, this is more correct

```
df = df[(0<df)&(df<100)]
sum_outside_0_100 = df.isna().sum().sum()
if sum_outside_0_100>0:
   print("DATA OUT OF RANGE")
else: 
   print(df)
```

Comment: Actually, I want to read and print the dataframe 'df' if all the columns values are within range 0 to 100, else want to print 'Data out of range'. It's give me the result true or false, but unable to print the df. Could you please help me out..?

Comment: Okay then checkout the new answer

Answer (score 1):

After clarifying question I've ended with this one line of code:

```
print("DATA OUT OF RANGE" if  df[(0<df)&(df<100)].isnull().values.any() else df)
```

Now above solution should meet requirements.

Comment: Dropna is not required, I want to read and print the dataframe 'df' if all the columns values are within range 0 to 100, else want to print 'Data out of range'. It's give me the result true or false, but unable to print the df. Could you please help me out..?

Comment: I've considered new requirements. Please see the solution provided.